# only one active element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a redux store where is `rooms` array stored (fetched from server) and in my component i fetch it from the store, map it and then display elements with value of room['foo'] but my problem is this: when the components are mapped and displayed the value of one that user clicks is going to be sent to server so i store clicked elements value in components local state like this:

```
...
handleRoomSelection(roomNumber,index,e){
    this.setState({
        room: roomNumber
    })
}
...
{this.props.rooms.map((val,i)=>{
   return (
      val.reserved === false ? <p className="" key={i} onClick={e => this.handleRoomSelection(val.roomNumber,i,e)}>{val.roomNumber}</p> : null
   ) 
})}
```

and this works fine, but my problem is that i want to add className "active" to active element (there can only be one active element) it would be easy if there could be many active elements (i would just add `e.target.className = "active"` after setState) so how can i achieve my aim?

Comment: which one is active?

Comment: the one that is clicked

Comment: it is supposed to be*

Comment: Side note: don't set `key={i}`, the key attribute is intended to identify elements in your list uniquely for diffing purposes, and "its position in the array" does _not_ identify rooms. Set `key={val.roomNumber}` instead.

Comment: isn't array index the unique?

Comment: No, you've used the array index, which only says something _for the array_. Say we have objects `a` and `b`, and an array `[a, b]`. Rearranging that array to `[b,a]` swaps `a` and `b`, but if you're keying on array index then React will not see that you swapped them, it will see that you completely rewrote arr[0] as well as arr[1], and will do _way_ more work than it needs to in order to get that update rendered. Your keys should be an identifier for the object that works irrespective of where in an array that object is.

Comment: but what if i have same values in array ? (i do not mean my current array every object in it has unique roomNumber) what should i set as keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just do what you stated: set the class based on the room number in your state. `setState` triggers `render()`, so enrich even though there's nothing active on first render, once you click, render triggers and we can just set that class inside your map:

```
render() {
  return this.props.rooms.map(val => {
    if (val.reserved) return null;

    return <p
      className={ this.state.room === val.roomNumber && `active`}
      key={val.roomNubber}
      onClick={() => this.handleRoomSelection(val.roomNumber)}
    >{val.roomNumber}</p>;
  };
}
```

Note that we've changed the `key` to something that uniquely identifies the *element* we're building a `<p>` for: never use array index as key, because array position does not identify any specific *element*, it only identifies a *position* in a list.

Also note that there's no reason to pass more than just the room number in your click handler if the handler itself only cares about the room number.

Comment: thanks, nice answer by the way i just forgot to delete index from event handler (i was trying something with it before)

Answer (score 1):

Compare the `room` in state to each room's `roomNumber` for defining the `className`

```js
{
  this.props.rooms.map((val, i) => {
    const className = this.state.room === val.roomNumber ? 'active' : '';
    
    return val.reserved === false ? (
      <p
        className={className}
        key={i}
        onClick={e => this.handleRoomSelection(val.roomNumber, i, e)}
      >
        {val.roomNumber}
      </p>
    ) : null;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use your state to populate `className` ?

```js
{this.props.rooms.map((val,i)=>{
   return (
      val.reserved === false
        ? <p
            className={val.roomNumber === this.state.room ? 'active' : ''}
            key={i}
            onClick={e => this.handleRoomSelection(val.roomNumber,i,e)}>
            {val.roomNumber}
          </p>
        : null

   ) 
})}
```